# How do I cook with Salsola (land seaweed)?

Tags: asian-cuisine

I've seen Salsola in buffets, but don't know how to prepare it. How do I prepare it, because I can't seem to find a recipe anywhere?

[image: seaweed salad]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Salsola soda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsola_soda)* can be eaten raw or sautéed quickly - as a very rough rule of thumb, think “spinach”.

If you are looking for recipes, it’s helpful to know that in Italian cuisine it’s called

> **Agretti** or
>   **Barba di frate**

If you search for one of these names plus “recipe”, you should find enough recipes to work from there.

Comment: This [article](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2012/may/25/alys-fowler-salsola) by Alys Fowler at _The Guardian_ discussing Salsola with tips on growing and preparing may be helpful to you.

Comment: @Stephie Also, from Wikipedia: S. soda is sometimes confused with a plant known in Japan as okahijiki (land seaweed), which is actually the species S. komarovi. The harvested leaves of the two species have a similar appearance. (Literally translated, Oka=land, hijiki=seaweed.)

Comment: So how do I make that land seaweed in buffets?

Comment: @acoder not answerable - there’s no “specific buffet preparation”. You need to analyze the dish in question or at least describe it in much more detail.

Comment: @Stephie this is all over the country

Comment: @acoder The country? Which country? Your country is not necessarily my or Stephie's country.

Comment: usa i used to travel a lot as a merchant marine. look at the picture.

Comment: i still have no luck finding recipes

Comment: I had no problem whatsoever when googling „barba di frate recipe“ or „agretti recipe“. You might want to start [here](http://foodblogga.blogspot.com/2011/06/what-is-agretti.html?m=1).